# What does an embodied companion (Strange Alchemies merit) use for Power + Finesse?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, promethean-the-created

I'm preparing to run a Promethean the Created game (1st edition) and one of my players is taking the Companion merit at 4 dots from Strange Alchemies (page 55).

It looks like the embodied spirit has the standard 3x3 attributes instead of just Power, Finesse, and Resistance, and has skills as well.

When it comes time to use its influence, Numina, or harvest essence, what does it roll if it doesn't have Power + Finesse?